# Grails redirect to another view or controller on delete

Tags: grails

Hi I'm using Grails controller to delete data from Domain Class and on successful delete I would like to redirect to a very specific page. Can someone tell me how to do that?
I Googled around and I found this link:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html
I'm just not sure how do I embed this in my controller's definition:

def delete(DomainClass domainClass){
   respond domainClass view: 'confirmDelete'
}

Comment: just put `redirect(action: "show")` into controller, instead of `render`

Comment: I'm actaully using respond to get to the view I created called confirmDelete. The delete button resides in confirmDelete.gsp changing to redirect (action: "something/show") will work if I put it right under respond?

Comment: my bad, did you mean add redirect into the def index(){} method?

Comment: I mean to put it after actual deletion (or where you need to make a redirect). and better to `return` it, to avoid code mistakes, mean `return redirect(view: xxxx)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are deleting an instance, let's say

```
Book.groovy // domain object
Bookcontroller.groovy // controller
```

then

```
// your delete logic
def delete() {
...
book.delete()// this performs the delete and upon successful deletion
redirect(controller: "book", action: "show")//you will be redirected to new page called show.gsp
...
}
```

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If redirecting to the same controller:

```
def delete() {
   // your delete code
   redirect action: "someAction"
}
```

If redirecting to another controller

```
def delete() {
   // your delete code
   redirect action: "someAction", controller: "someController"
}
```